# Divide list elements with dictionary values in python

Tags: python, arrays, python-3.x, dictionary

I have a dictionary as:

```
d=[{'court': 4, 'hope': 6},
 {'court': 9, 'hope': 27},
 {'hope': 5, 'mention': 2, 'life': 10, 'bolster': 1, 'internal': 15, 'level': 1}]
```

and list

```
l=[2, 9, 5]
```

All I want to divide the list elements with correponding dictionary values. something,

```
new_list=[{'court': 2, 'hope': 3},
 {'court': 1, 'hope': 3},
 {'hope': 1, 'mention': 0.4, 'life': 2, 'bolster': 0.2, 'internal': 3,'level': 0.2}]
```

All I did,

```
new_list=[]
for i in d:
    for k,j in i.items():
        new={k:j/o for o in l}
        new_list.append(new)
```

it returns as list with individual elements:

```
[{'court': 2},{'hope': 3},
 {'court': 1},{'hope': 3},
 {'hope': 1},{'mention': 0.4},{'life': 2},{'bolster': 0.2},{'internal': 3},{'level': 0.2}]
```

Answer (score 3):

With simple list/dict comprehension:

```
res = [{k: v/divider for k,v in d[i].items()} for i, divider in enumerate(l)]
print(res)
```

The output:

```
[{'court': 2.0, 'hope': 3.0}, {'court': 1.0, 'hope': 3.0}, {'hope': 1.0, 'mention': 0.4, 'life': 2.0, 'bolster': 0.2, 'internal': 3.0, 'level': 0.2}]
```

---

Or the same with `zip` function:

```
res = [{k: v/divider for k,v in d.items()} for d, divider in zip(d, l)]
```

Answer (score 0):

**1. Hard Way(most understandable way)**

```py
for i in range(len(l)):
     for key, value in d[i].items():
          val = value / l[i]
          if val.is_integer():
               d[i][key] = int(val)
          else:
               d[i][key] = val

print(d)
```

**2. using [`zip()`](https://docs.python.org/3.3/library/functions.html#zip) python [Built-in Functions](https://docs.python.org/3.3/library/functions.html#built-in-functions)**

```py
d = [{key: (int(value/divider) if (value/divider).is_integer() else value/divider) for key,value in d.items()} for d, divider in zip(d, l)]
print(d)
```

**3. using [`enumerate()`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#enumerate) python [Built-in Functions](https://docs.python.org/3.3/library/functions.html#built-in-functions)**

```py
d = [{key: (int(value/divider) if (value/divider).is_integer() else value/divider) for key,value in d[i].items()} for i, divider in enumerate(l)]
print(d)
```

Those 3 methods giving you the same output which you expected:

```sh
[{'court': 2, 'hope': 3},
 {'court': 1, 'hope': 3},
 {'hope': 1, 'mention': 0.4, 'life': 2, 'bolster': 0.2, 'internal': 3, 'level': 0.2}]
```